# Get the index of errors comes from backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object with some arrays that are representing error messages. So, I am trying to show the error message per row like that:
**Row 1: "This is error message 1"**
**Row 4: "This is error message 4"**

and the errors comes:

```
const errors = {
   product[0].Name: ["This is error message"],
   product[4].Name: ["This is error message"],
 }
```

I tried to get key names:

```
Object.keys(errors)
```

but then I am not able to get this row number.

Comment: Not clear your question. Which row number? are you asking for array index?

Comment: I am trying to get the index 0 and 4 in that case.

Comment: Can you add the code snippet  for `product` as well ?

Comment: This comes from api.

Answer (score 0):

This must solve the problem for you:

```
const product = [{"Name": "One"},{"Name": "Twp"},{"Name": "three"},{"Name": "Four"}];

const productOne = product[0].Name;
const productTwo = product[3].Name;

const errors = {
   productOne : ["This is error message"],
   productTwo : ["This is error message"],
};

console.log(Object.keys(errors));
```

Explanation:

What you were trying to do is evaluate the expression `product[0].Name` for an Object key, which is not possible, and not allowed.

Hence, what you can do it evaluate them beforehand, store them and use it directly.